# create new Docker image using the existing docker image

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a docker image in docker registry. I need to run build(eg. running build on a master branch of the application) on this docker image and create new Docker image using the existing docker image.

I am trying to achieve this using Jenkins job?

Is it possible to achieve via shell script? Any suggestions.

Comment: Your questions is unfortunately not very clear. If you want to create a new docker image using an existing docker image, you can write a docker file using the existing image as the base and add your modifications on top of it before you do a 'docker build'

Comment: is there a way to put the docker file in jenkins job?

Comment: You should read Docker's [official tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/): a Dockerfile exactly declares a base image to start `FROM` and a set of commands to `RUN` to build a new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a Dockerfile in which you define the FROM:image-present-repo

then add your build steps in Dockerfile

Once you have the Dockerfike ready. In Jenkins job just use the docker build command referencing the Dockerfile

Comment: Is there any way i could write the docker file contents in the jenkins job somewhere?